# AutoMapper 10.0 failing with message "Instance property 'Current' is not defined for type 'System.Collections.IDictionaryEnumerator'"

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, automapper

I'm using [`AutoMapper`](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) in a project, and it was using version `9.0.0` along with version `7.0.0` of [`AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection`](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection), and everything was working.

I have a call to `GetService` on my `IServiceProvider` to resolve a service, and after upgrading to version `10.0.0` (and version `8.0.1` of the DI project), the call is failing with the following message:

```
'Instance property 'Current' is not defined for type 'System.Collections.IDictionaryEnumerator'
```

I tried to look into the code to see if I can find out why it's happening, but I wasn't successful.

Although I did find that [this line](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/eafff201494a6aa3cd07159048f4722ec7509d16/src/AutoMapper/Internal/ExpressionFactory.cs#L146) in the source code is failing for me

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: I know! I completely agree with you, and in fact, after posting the question, I thought to myself that the question is too vague  ... my source code is too big to be posted anywhere (in fact, it's company code), but I'll try to see if I can find a way to reproduce it

Comment: The source code has already update here. https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/pull/3156/files

Comment: your issue  is same with this [#1711](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/pull/1711)

Comment: @Lightman thank you for your comments, but I didn't quite get it! The first one seems to be a PR that was closed (not merged?), and the second one seems to be very old. So I guess whatever change is there should have already been there and not introduced between version 9.0 to 10.0 (which is the breaker for me)

Comment: @Farzad, sorry for confusing u, and in my first sight of your post, I thought it might be a bug of the updated version. Maybe you could try posting this issue on AutoMapper
 [github](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues).

Comment: Thank you @Lightman; I guess I'll try that 

Comment: We get the same error happening, @Farzad did you ever get down to the bottom of it?

Comment: UPDATE: In our case adding ".ForAllOtherMembers( _ => _.Ignore() )" ended up resolving it. See logged issue [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/3552)